# Is storing secret in bitbucket pipeline variable safe?

Tags: security, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

As part of my Bitbucket pipeline task i am invoking a web call which needs password. If I store the password as secret variable in bitbucket pipeline is it safe? If not what are other options available?

Comment: Define `safe`...

Comment: Usually, people didn't store the password and it is in the extra config files not uploaded into anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a repository variable and reference it in your pipeline.

You can store the value as secured, such that no-one can view the value once saved.

Read more here: https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/